# Find the radius of convergence of the power series

Tags: convergence-divergence, complex-numbers, power-series

$\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nz^n$, where $a_{2k+1} = 2^k$ and $a_{2k} = (1 + (1/k))^2$ for $k = 0, 1, 2, \dotsc$

I started off by doing the ratio test, but I know that the ration test is for $|a_{k+1} |/|a_k|$ and here they throw in the $2k+1$ so I am utterly lost and don't know how to start. can anyone help?

Comment: Do you know the Cauchy-Hadamard formula?

Comment: no we havent learned that yet

Comment: I've been doing the ratio test but I keep getting a mess of an answer

Comment: You should not be getting a mess of an answer, because in fact you should be getting no answer, as the ratio test does not apply directly.

Comment: Split the series into two parts, one for the even-indexed coefficients, one for the odd-indexed. Compute the radius of convergence for both subseries. The radius of convergence of the combined sequence is easily determined from those two radii.

Comment: can someone show me how that would be set up?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Cauchy-Hadamard makes it really simple here since

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sup\sqrt[n]{a_n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sup\begin{cases}\sqrt[n]{2^n}\\{}\\\sqrt[n]{\left(1+\frac1n\right)^2}\end{cases}\;\;=2$$

and the radius of convergence is thus $\;1/2\;$ .

Using the ratio test for odd/even-indexed subsequences:

$$\frac{a_{2n+2}}{a_{2n}}=\frac{\left(1+\frac1{n+1}\right)^2}{\left(1+\frac1n\right)2}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}1$$

$$\frac{a_{2n+1}}{a_{2n-1}}=\frac{2^n}{2^{n-1}}=2$$

and we're done (why? Why can we split the sequence as above and do the ratio test separatedly) and then we choose the minimal one?)

Comment: thanks so much! I've been trying to debunk this problem for days!

Comment: WAIT! i am looking at the problem and it says that a_2k = (1 + (1/k))^(k^2)... its not just squared its k^2 .. will this change the answer or the way to do it?

Comment: @user134982 , it's the same procedure...and if you wrote with LaTeX these problems would not usually happen.

Comment: This solution is incorrect. The first calculation needs to have $\sqrt[2n+1]{2^n}$ in place of $\sqrt[n]{2^n}$. In the second calculation, the fact that the latter limit is $2$, combined with the fact that the ratio of the powers of $z$ is $z^2$ (not $z$), means that the radius of convergence is in fact $\sqrt2$, not $2$. As a test case, consider $a_{2n+1}=2^n$ while $a_{2n}=0$; this is a geometric series whose radius of convergence can be easily found directly, but your calculation will get the same wrong answer as it does here.