# $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}a_k(z+4)^k$ with $a_{2j}=(\sqrt{3})^{2j}$, different solutions

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series

I want to calculate the radius of convergence of the series $$\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}a_k(z+4)^k$$ where $a_{2j}=(\sqrt{3})^{2j}$ and $a_{2j-1}=\frac{1}{2j-1}$. I would calculate the radius of convergence for the even and odd terms seperatly and then take the minimum of both solutions. But for "$k$ even" I get different solutions and I'm don't know what is wrong here.

One the one hand I get: $$\frac{1}{\limsup\limits_{j\to\infty}((\sqrt{3})^{2j})^{\frac{1}{2j} }}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}},$$but on the other hand I get:$$\lim\limits_{j\to \infty}|\frac{(\sqrt{3})^{2j}}{(\sqrt{3})^{2(j+1)}}|=\lim\limits_{j\to \infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}^{2}}=\frac{1}{3}.$$ So something goes wrong here, but I don't know where is the mistake. I appreciate your help

The calculation $\lim\limits_{j\to \infty}|\frac{(\sqrt{3})^{2j}}{(\sqrt{3})^{2j+1}}|=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$ gives me the same solution, but the odd coefficients of the series are not $(\sqrt{3})^{2j}$.

Comment: The second calculation is wrong. The ratio-test calculation of radius of convergence assumes that the powers of $(z+4)$ on consecutive terms differ by $1$, but here those powers differ by $2$ on the even terms. (Remind yourself how to derive the radius of convergence from the ratio test calculation; you'll see what happened.)

Comment: Thanks! I first thought that this could be a problem, but here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/709720/find-the-radius-of-convergence-of-the-power-series he does the same calculation

Comment: That's a valid concern, but that solution is incorrect. As I suggest there, change this problem to the test case $a_{2j}=(\sqrt3)^{2j}$ and $a_{2j-1}=0$; one can evaluate that geometric series exactly and spot its smallest singularity, and thereby see how the wrong methods give the wrong answer.